# Set ActiveStorage disk service upload paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Does anyone know how to change the disk_service.rb to specify upload paths, for example:

```
my_path = Rails.root.join("public", "websites", "example.com", "users", current_user.id, "avatar")
current_user.avatar.attach(file, my_path)
```

This would result in having the file uploaded here:

```
/public/websites/example.com/users/12345/avatar/blah.png
```

And then I'd be able to:

```
rails_representation_path( current_user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100"), disposition: 'attachment')
```

and get back the path:

```
/websites/example.com/users/12345/avatar/blah-100x100.png
```

This will allow getting rid of many issues around the ActiveStorage public/private URLs and related to CDN caching.

I am playing with https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/disk_service.rb but can't figure out much of what it does and how it works really.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to make active storage work, but I kept bumping into limitations for frustratingly simple use-cases that aren't supported and cannot be easily implemented, so I ended up going with Shrine which is HEAVEN for anything files related. If you are not too deep into the project, go with Shrine.

Comment: It seems we're not the only ones running into trouble with ActiveStorage. Fortunately I haven't gone too far with it and will likely switch very soon.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/storage.yml` you should have a configuration block for the local storage service, you can change where the attachments are stored by specifing a different path for root.

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join('storage') %>
```

I don't think that you'll be able to address the specific images in the manner you are describing.  ActiveRecord creates a unique key for everything that is attached to a model and renames the files with that key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I will still need to be able to specify file names and paths for each image. Looks like it’s a no go with AS, will be switching to Shrine soon.